# A function of "that" in "who are you that you are afraid of man"

Tags: terminology, conjunctions

> I, I am he who comforts you; who are you that you are afraid of man who dies, of the son of man who is made like grass, 
>   (Isaiah 51:12 , English Standard Version ©2001)

How to express the function of "that" in the sentence in grammatical terms? A coordinating conjunction?

Answer (score 1):

"That" functions as a [subordinating conjunction](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000370.htm) in the sentence:

> Who are you?

is the main clause.

> You are afraid of man who dies....

is the subordinate clause.

["That" doesn't function as a relative pronoun in this sentence but as a subordinating conjunction. It doesn't matter what part of speech it is but what it does in the sentence.](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/conjunctions.htm)

To function as a relative pronoun, it would have to replace a noun phrase in the sentence, e.g.:

> This is *the house* **that** Jack built.

In this sentence, *that* is a relative pronoun that replaces *the house*:

> Jack built *that*; Jack built *the house*.

The relative pronoun in "This is *the house* **that** Jack built" (**that**) also subordinates the dependent clause to the main clause. "That Jack built" isn't an independent clause unless "That" is the demonstrative pronoun "that" and the sentence is pronounced with heavy stress on "That". In that case, there should probably be a comma after "That": "That, Jack built" to indicate a slight pause, but it's not necessary.

It's not normal word order in most cases, but it's certainly possible and not even uncommon. Scenario: a wall with three paintings.

A: See those paintings?
B: Yes.
A: Well, this John did [pointing at first painting]. That Jack did [pointing at second painting]. And that I did [pointing at third painting]. Which do you like?
B: Well, this I don't like, that I like, and that third one I don't like at all.

Comment: A complementizer, not a conjunction. But complementizers are available only in modern parts of speech, not in the Elite Eight.

Comment: "[In linguistics (especially generative grammar), **a complementizer (or complementiser) is a syntactic category (part of speech) roughly equivalent to the term subordinating conjunction in traditional grammar**. For example, the word that is generally called a complementizer in English sentences like Mary believes that it is raining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementizer)." I'm just using the terminology I found on the Net & that I remember from decades ago. I defer to your expertise, of course, because this is your field, but it seems to me that this is a terminological quagmire.

Comment: @JohnLawler: I was actually thinking of adding something like "_Such that_ can replace **that** in _who are you that you are afraid of man who dies_", but I wasn't sure enough that it was true. Thank you for verifying it for me.

Comment: Not really. There's a small set of grammatical categories (POS) that are clearly necessary for English. As listed (p 12, fn 13 [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/McCawley-Lg.pdf)), they are limited to **N, V, P, A, Adv**, their respective projections (clauses and phrases that act as N, V, P, A, Adv), 
and distinguishing **N'** (an N projection) from **NP** (which is not, like N', a phrase headed by an N, but rather is a different
type, outside the X-Bar system – NP is the syntactic constituent type corresponding to the logical type _Argument of Predicate_).

Comment: The various machinery to fit these categories into sentences (semantically bleached articles, determiners, quantifiers, auxiliary verbs, prepositions, etc.) are more or less shoveled in by selecting the V, N, A, or Adv that governs them. Think of them as the little screws and plugs that come in a plastic bag when you're assembling an IKEA chair.

Comment: @JohnLawler: I supppose all of these use the same type of "that":
#1 It must have been pretty rough, that he looks that worn out.  #2 What has happened to you that you are so sad? #3 Who are you that you dare to speak so boldly? #4 I wonder what her job is, that she can afford a Porsche. 
What about the comma? I might be wrong, but something makes me feel that it should be used with declarative clauses and shouldn't with direct  questions. I am not sure about indirect questions like in #4.

Comment: @Osika: yes, those appear to be the same kind of clause. Commas are used, as always, when the intonation demands them.